# gridview get data of textbox after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm using a gridview control in asp.net

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text=''></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

user enter a value in a texbox 
after clicking a button get the value of textbox at run time. i'm nothing to perform this 
-------------------button click event----------

```
        foreach(GridViewRow gridviewrow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if(Convert.ToString(((TextBox)gridviewrow.FindControl("TextBox2")))!="")
            {
                donamount.Amount=((TextBox)gridviewrow.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
                donorinfo.Add(donamount);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you are not getting the `value` entered in `Textbox` to compare it in `if` condition.

**Solution :** you need to use the `Text` property of the `TextBox2` to get the `string` to compare it in `if` condition.
use `Trim()` function to remove the `white spaces` before comparing with `Empty String`.

**Try This:(Code Behind)**

```
foreach(GridViewRow gridviewrow in GridView1.Rows)
{                
    if(((TextBox)gridviewrow.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text.Trim()!="")
    {
      donamount.Amount=((TextBox)gridviewrow.FindControl("TextBox2")).Text;
      donorinfo.Add(donamount);
    }

}
```